# Guild Roster Sheet - Setting value row-by-row in one column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm just starting to learn how to code with Google Apps Script. Barely.

I have a guild roster sheet (toon names in range B2:B and Realm (We also add prospects to this list) in range C2:C.

In Column D, I would like to set the value of each cell row-by-row to a function that uses the data in B and C (i.e. "=wowi(B2,C2)")

My intent is to just be able to add as many names as I want in Column B, and run the function manually to update the values for each in column D, and sleeps for a second between each (so as to not abuse the UrlFetch in the "=wowi(toonName, realmName)" function when the names column gets a little long)

Sadly, this is about as far as I got before I gave up:

```
  function rosterUpdate() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var destCell = sheet.getRange("D2");
for (x = 0, x //(less than or equal to)// sheet.getRange("B2:B").getNumRows(), x ++) {
  if (x != 0 {
      NOCLUEWHATTODO-IDKWHYIEVENTRY;
      sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

}

I know I need to use a for, but not quite sure on how to go about reading the value and modifying the D cell's value. I'm quite possibly overthinking this, as it's currently 5:30 in the morning and I'm running on about 2 hours of sleep, but would really appreciate the help.

Thanks in advance. Sorry if I'm bad. :[

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this answers your question in terms of getting and setting values (you should check the documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) and how to sleep for one second between function calls, however it's pretty inefficient as it will iterate over the whole list each time.

Please be aware this is written off the top of my head very quickly so you may need to play with the i values to get it working properly, and there is probably a much, much cleaner way to do it!

```
    var listLength = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;

    for(var i = 0; i < listLength; i++){
      var toonName = sheet.getRange("B" + (i+2)).getValue();
      var realmName = sheet.getRange("C" + (i+2)).getValue();
      sheet.getRange("D" + (i+2)).setValue(yourFunction(toonName, realmName));
      Utilities.sleep(1000);
    }
```